# Root complete history commands

Tags: bash, command-history, audit

Where can I get root's history except besides `.sh_history`? I've gotten some information but only from `.sh_history` and the `history` command.

Answer (score 3):

That's the only place you'll find it unless the system has auditing enabled. In which case, depending on how the auditing is setup, you'll get a detailed list of the commands that were run.

What gets logged when using auditing (`auditd` is the service you have to have installed) is a pretty broad question, I'd check out the documentation if you're interested in exploring that further.

- [Chapter 30. Understanding Linux Audit](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-security_sd_draft/cha.audit.comp.html)

But again this is not typically enabled by default so you'd need to check with your admins of the system to see if it's enabled. If it isn't, then your only course of action to getting a history of the root user's history is from the history file that the shell maintains, typically `/root/.bash_history` if the account is setup to use Bash as the shell.